Obtain a directory path from a handle on Windows XP
My program is running on Windows XP.
I have an open handle to a directory, and I want the path.
If it were a regular file, I could do this, but if it were Windows Vista and above, I could use GetFinalPathNameByHandle().
Is there any way to go from a directory handle to the path to that directory on Windows XP?
